# Перенос сайта на другой сервер

Tags: linux, архивация

Всем привет!
Нужно перенести сайт на wordpress, папака upload занимает около 3ГБ и это все фото. Но вот имена файлов самые разнообразные. И на русском языке и на испанском, в общем на самых разных языках. Так вот, при распаковке архива файлы на новом сервере изменяются и соответственно сайт уже не выглядит как нужно.
Как можно решить эту проблему? 
ОС с которого переносится сайт Centos. ОС на которую переезжает сайт Debian.

Comment: меняются файлы или имена файлом (потому что запаковали неверно)?

Comment: меняются имена файлов, сами файлы вроде в порядке. архив сжимается в cpanel. через консоль если создать архив, решится проблема?

Comment: могли к примеру архивировать в обычный zip без поддержи utf-8. Скорее всего нужно перепаковать правильно.

Comment: Как вы архивируете и как распаковываете? Может, просто `rsync -avz ./www-root login:pwd@123.456.789.012//var/www/newsite` перенести безо всяких архивов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь консольными утилитами для сжатия и архивации. Например, `7z` (если он присутствует на сервере), он хранит кодировку имен файлов внутри себя в `utf-16` и при распаковке преобразует кодировку обратно в системную локаль ([man 7z](http://linux.die.net/man/1/7z)). Или используйте `tar` с опцией `--format=posix`, он преобразует кодировку в `utf8` при запаковке и вернет ее обратно при распаковке. Вместе с `tar` используйте опции сжатия ([man tar](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1)).

Например,

```
7z a bp.7z /var/www/site
```

или

```
tar --format=posix -cjf bp.tar.bz2 site -C /var/www
```

Comment: Не стоило мне распаковывать архив у себя на компьютере (Windows). Распаковывая архив на сервере куда переношу данные таких проблем не увидел. Спасибо за ответы, вопрос закрыт.